# Why this signal is not working as expected?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, signals

I would appreciate some help. Does anyone know why this signal is only being triggered only when the "xp value" is different from the one that already exist ? so eg.  if a  UserLeaderboardTracking objects already exist for that user with the value 10 the it won't create it otherwise it will .

```
    def create_user_leaderboard_tracking(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        if instance.xp_collected == 0:
            pass
        else:
            UserLeaderboardTracking.objects.get_or_create(user=instance.user,
                                                          xp_value=instance.xp_collected)
```

Comment: can you share `UserLeaderboardTracking` Model?

Comment: not sure to understand, yoiu speak about XP value of 10 but your condition is about 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using <get_or_create> and instead I should have use

````
def create_user_leaderboard_tracking(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        if instance.xp_collected == 0:
            pass
        else:
            UserLeaderboardTracking.objects.create(user=instance.user,
                                                   xp_value=instance.xp_collected) ```
````

Comment: It is working now, the issue was only because I was using get_or_create !

Comment: If anyone would like to know how I've create a Leadeboard based on Day, Week and Month just ask :)